# Select with custom field

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity `toy` with many properties but also a few OneToMany and ManyToOne relations. To get all entries where column `deleted` is not `true` I would write:

```
findAll() {
  return this.toyRepository.find({
    where: {
      deleted: Not(true)
    }
  });
}
```

It gets all entries I want but this entity has a ManyToOne relation to `user`. I want to get all entries but with an extra property `user` that contains only the username of that user. I can load the whole relation if adding `relations: ['user']` but that's not what I want.

So I need to use the querybuilder. I came up with:

```
return this.toyRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('toy')
  .select('toy.*')
  .addSelect('userEntity.username', 'user')
  .where('toy.deleted != 1')
  .leftJoin('toy.user', 'userEntity')
  .getRawMany();
```

This will get the entries I want but contains all other ManyToOne relations with a `null` value (if there is no entry connected to it) like "manufacturerId", "userId", "brandId", etc. I want the entry without the relation connection.

The only way I know is to not use `toy.*` and use `toy.id, toy.name, toy.descritpion, toy.serial, toy.serial2, toy.size, [many more ...]` instead, but it doesn't seem right to hardcode all column names.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `find()` call, you can make use of `relations` and `select` attributes

```
findAll() {
  return this.toyRepository.find({
    where: {
      deleted: Not(true)
    },
    relations: {
      user: true
    },
    select: {
      user: {
        id: true,
        username: true,
        // ... any other columns that you want to select
      }
    }
  });
}
```